# Optimize query with multiple calls to the same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We are creating a view as follows:

```
create view [dca].[CodeDescriptions_VW]
as 
    select distinct 
        ek.EmpKey
        , RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(60), abt.fdesc)) AS AboriginalTypeDescription
        , RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(60), cma.fdesc)) AS CensusMetroAreaDescription
        , RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(60), q.c_desc)) AS CobraCodeDescription
        , RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(60), ct.fdesc)) AS ConsentTypeDescription
        , RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(60), li.fdesc)) AS DirectOrIndirectDescription
        , RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(60), dt.fdesc)) AS DisabilityTypeDescription
        , RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(60), doca.fdesc)) AS DocumentADescription
    FROM  
        dbo.hrpersnl AS h 
    INNER JOIN 
        HRActions.dbo.EmployeeKey AS ek ON RTRIM(LTRIM(UPPER(h.p_empno))) = UPPER(ek.EmpNo) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
                                        AND h.p_company = ek.Company COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        dbo.hrtables AS abt ON abt.ftable = ''AL'' AND RTRIM(h.p_abotype) = RTRIM(abt.code)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        dbo.hrtables AS cma ON cma.ftable = ''CM'' AND RTRIM(h.p_cma) = RTRIM(cma.code) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        dbo.hrtables AS ct ON ct.ftable = ''CS'' AND RTRIM(h.p_constype) = RTRIM(ct.code)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        dbo.hrtables AS li ON li.ftable = ''IN'' AND RTRIM(h.p_laborind) = RTRIM(li.code)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        dbo.hrtables AS dt ON dt.ftable = ''DI'' AND RTRIM(h.p_distype) = RTRIM(dt.code)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        dbo.hrtables AS doca ON doca.ftable = ''I2'' AND RTRIM(h.p_doca) = RTRIM(doca.code)
```

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to reference the same table (`dbo.hratables`) multiple times. As is, this is a very costly view (there are actually about 3 dozen different 'Descriptions' that we need to query, I have only shown a few).

Comment: What's going on with the INNER JOIN conditions?  Why is switching collations  necessary to compare table keys?  It's unlikely to be using indexes

Comment: @SteveC The two tables involved in that INNER JOIN are from different databases, one we do not control.  Depending on how users setup that DB (i.e., case sensitive on/off) we need to do the COLLATE.

Comment: All your join conditions are different, i.e. you are joining on different rows in the table, so unlikely you can improve it.

Comment: That's unfortunate but it's always like that :)  Well, could try to create an indexed view on re-collated columns from dbo.hrpersnl and then use that view in this view.

Answer (score 0):

While not ideal, perhaps you could create an in-line TVF and use that vs all the joins.

Something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.HRDescription ( 
    @ftable VARCHAR(2), @code VARCHAR(50), @field VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT RTRIM( CONVERT( VARCHAR(60), 
        CASE
            WHEN @field = 'c_desc' THEN c_desc
            ELSE fdesc
        END ) ) AS [Value]
    FROM dbo.hrtables
    WHERE
        ftable = @ftable AND RTRIM( code ) = @code
)
GO
```

And then modify your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ek.EmpKey
    , ( SELECT [Value] FROM dbo.HRDescription( 'AL', h.p_abotype, 'fdesc' ) ) AS AboriginalTypeDescription
    , ( SELECT [Value] FROM dbo.HRDescription( 'CM', h.p_cma, 'fdesc' ) ) AS CensusMetroAreaDescription
    , ( SELECT [Value] FROM dbo.HRDescription( 'CS', h.p_constype, 'fdesc' ) ) AS ConsentTypeDescription
    , ( SELECT [Value] FROM dbo.HRDescription( 'IN', h.p_laborind, 'fdesc' ) ) AS DirectOrIndirectDescription
    , ( SELECT [Value] FROM dbo.HRDescription( 'DI', h.p_distype, 'fdesc' ) ) AS DisabilityTypeDescription
    , ( SELECT [Value] FROM dbo.HRDescription( 'I2', h.p_doca, 'fdesc' ) ) AS DocumentADescription
FROM dbo.hrpersnl AS h 
INNER JOIN HRActions.dbo.EmployeeKey AS ek 
    ON RTRIM(LTRIM(UPPER(h.p_empno))) = UPPER(ek.EmpNo) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
    AND h.p_company = ek.Company COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
```

Again, not ideal, but it may save on performance over the joins.